# Firestore How to retrieve document's autogenerated id in the past?

Tags: firebase, dart, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

In Firestore, I have added a single document in a subcollection, I don't know its id because it was added in the past, but I know its path. How to get its id ? Should I save its id at the creation?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I don't know its id because it was added in the past, **but I know its
> path**.

If with "I know its path" you refer to the **Document path**, then the Document ID is the last element of the path, in which elements are separated by a slash. For example `rootCollectionName/parentDocId/parentCollectionName/docId`.

---

If with "I know its path" you refer to the **path of the subcollection**, then you could query the subcollection and take the first document, since there is a single doc in the collection.

For example with Dart:

```
QuerySnapshot querySnapshot = await Firestore.instance.collection("rootCollectionName/parentDocId/parentCollectionName").get();
var documentID = querySnapshot.docs[0].id;
```

Comment: Thanks, the second example is what I need. Btw, can I give my document the same id as parentDocId's id ? It works but, is it correct ?

Comment: "can I give my document the same id as parentDocId's id" Yes you can very well do that. Actually from a technical perspective, a root collection and one of its sub-collections are not at all related to each other. They just share a part of their path but nothing else.